# Java sync external files read write

Tags: java, multithreading

I would like to create a pipe for read/write data between 2 JVM process (not the same process). Im using a FIFO pipe in Unix to share the data.

I did a Reader:

```
/** Read a named pipe file */
public class PipeReader {

private String path;

public PipeReader (String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public String readpipe () throws IOException { 
    String res = null;
    RandomAccessFile pipe = null;

    try {
        // Connect to the named pipe
        pipe = new RandomAccessFile (path, "r");

        // Read response from pipe
        while (true) {
           res = pipe.readLine();
           System.out.println("Read message:" + res);   
        }    
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        pipe.close();
    }
    return res;
}
```

And a Writer using FileLock:

```
public class PipeWriter {

private String path;

public PipeWriter (String path) {
    this.path = path;
}

public String writepipe (String mm) throws IOException { 
    String res = null;
    RandomAccessFile pipe = null;
    try {
        // Connect to the named pipe
        pipe = new RandomAccessFile (path, "rw");
        FileChannel channel = pipe.getChannel();
        int i = 0;
        while (i<5) {   
            // Write request to the pipe
            FileLock lock = channel.lock();
            pipe.write(mm.getBytes());
            lock.release();
            System.out.println("PipeWriten" + mm);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            i++;
        }



        // do something with res
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        // Close the pipe
        pipe.close();
    }


    return res;
}
```

The first time pipe.readLine() block this thread and wait until PipeWriter write a line in the pipe and release the lock, when the writer finishes the reader read it. This is the behavior until PipeWriter finishes (after the 5 writings). After that, pipe.readLine() don't block the thread and continues looping the reading so I get "Read message: null" a lot of times. How could I fix it? I think I am missing something in the Reader. Are there any method to synchronize a file shared by 2 process, not using FileLock? (something like semaphores but for processes, not threads).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is in the writer. If the writer is supposed to be waitable, it needs to keep the pipe open.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I removed the pipe.close() from the writer, but I get the same issue.

Comment: You got null reads while the pipe was opened for writing in another process? Are you sure?

Comment: I answer in a post with an image. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pipe's not like a file (which is good, since you can't wait for a file) it's a connection between the reader and the writer. It's more like a telephone. When the other side hangs up, you have to hang up too. Then you can wait for the next call.

When `read` gets zero, that means the connection is now closed, and you should close the pipe. If you want to wait for a new connection, re-open the pipe.

Comment: Thanks a lot! now I understand it :D

Answer (score 0):

This is what I get: In the beginning, Reader is blocked waiting in pipe.readLine(). When Writer write a line and release the locker it read it. But then the Writer finishes, the Reader don't wait in readLine() anymore, and read null all the time.

[image]

Comment: When the writer finishes, there's nothing to wait for anymore. No more data will flow over the connection, so what would the point of waiting be?

Comment: It's a simulation, in the program, the writer will open the pipe and write, and the reader should be waiting always to read this data.

Comment: How can the reader wait to read data when it has no connection? Surely you mean that while there's a writer, it should be waiting to read data from it. But when the writer terminates, it should close the dead connection and wait for a new one, not continue to wait on a dead connection.